# ZSH no module named numpy for python3 interpreter and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, bash, numpy, jupyter-notebook, zsh

I have a question about zsh and numpy module for python3.
I have problem with python3 interpreter and jupyter notebook, when I open my console by default `/bin/zsh` now and enter to python3 interpreter after importing module 'numpy' it could not find it, but when I start `/bin/zsh` go to bash and then to zsh it magically appeared I don't know where the problem is, I've searched through `$PATH` and rc srcipt for zsh and I found nothing.[just ignore my cd ./- login script command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTrBn.png)

Comment: Your paths are different, try `which python3` in both and update your `PATH` environment variable for `zsh`.

Comment: have two paths to python3 one for /bin/ and second for anaconda /home/rr/anadonda3/bin/python3  and /bin... was first in PATH, Thank you ;)